# Java (Swing) - How to rotate a bunch of lines?

Tags: java, swing

I've been looking for this online, but I can't seem to find how to rotate a bunch of lines. I made a "plane" with the `Graphics.drawLine()` function, but I want to know how to rotate the whole thing 90 degrees to the right when it hits a wall. Here is my current code:

```
/* MovePlane
 * Moves plane to the right, down, left, up, and repeats using Timer object
 */

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class MovePlane extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   private int delay = 5;
   private Timer timer;

   private int x = 10;      // x position
   private int y = 10;      // y position

   private boolean right = true;
   private boolean up = true;

   public MovePlane() {
       timer = new Timer(delay, this);
       timer.start();       // start the timer - infinite
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // will run when the timer fires
       repaint();
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       // both paint and paintComponent work - difference?
       super.paintComponent(g);    // call superclass's paintComponent 
       g.drawLine(x,y,x+20,y);               // body - drawn in terms of x
       g.drawLine(x+15,y-5,x+15,y+5);    // wing
       g.drawLine(x,y-2,x,y+2);  
       if (right && up) {
            x++;
            if (x == getWidth()-25) {
                right = false;
                up = false;
            }
       } else if (!right && !up) {
            y++;
            if (y == getHeight()-10) {
                up = true;
            }
       } else {
            if (x <= getWidth()-15 && x > 0) {
                x--;
            }
            if (x == 0) {
                y--;
            }
            if (y == 10) {
                right = true;
            }
       }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Move Plane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MovePlane bp = new MovePlane(); 
        frame.add(bp);
        frame.setSize(300, 300); // set frame size
        frame.setVisible(true); // display frame
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a `AffineTransform` [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275424/rotating-image-with-affinetransform/20280225#20280225), while this simply rotates an `Image`, the basic concept is the same, you can "transform" the `Graphics` context and anything painted after it will have the transformation applied to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it everytime you change the direction, so, you need to move your `g.drawLine(...)` calls inside each `if` conditions...

But while rotating the plane, you also need to take care of the "bounds" or the limits of the screen, so, I modified `if (x == 0)` and `... && x > 0` conditions to have a gap of `20` instead...

Let's start for the plane going from left to right:

```
g.drawLine(x, y, x + 20, y);               // body - drawn in terms of x
g.drawLine(x + 15, y - 5, x + 15, y + 5);    // wing
g.drawLine(x, y - 2, x, y + 2);
```

This is telling us that:

- Your plane's body length is 20
- Your wings are 15 units from the back
- Your tail is right on the back

So, to change it to move from left to right, we need to invert the wings and tail positions...

- Plane lenght is still the same
- Wings are now 5 units from the back
- Tail is now on the front

Then, we have this code:

```
g.drawLine(x, y, x + 20, y);               // Body length 20
g.drawLine(x + 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5);    // Wing's are 5 units from the front
g.drawLine(x + 20, y - 2, x + 20, y + 2);  // Tail is on the front (at body's length)
```

And for when going down:

- Body's length is now on Y axis
- Wings should be at 15 units from the back
- Tail is at the back

So we have:

```
g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 20);               // Body is now on Y axis
g.drawLine(x - 5, y + 15, x + 5, y + 15);    // Wings are 15 units from the back
g.drawLine(x - 2, y, x + 2, y); // Tail is on the back
```

And applying same logic as when going from right to left:

```
g.drawLine(x, y + 20, x, y);
g.drawLine(x - 5, y + 5, x + 5, y + 5);
g.drawLine(x - 2, y + 20, x + 2, y + 20);
```

Then your `paintComponent(...)` method looks like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // both paint and paintComponent work - difference?
    super.paintComponent(g);    // call superclass's paintComponent
    if (right && up) {
        g.drawLine(x, y, x + 20, y);               // body - drawn in terms of x
        g.drawLine(x + 15, y - 5, x + 15, y + 5);    // wing
        g.drawLine(x, y - 2, x, y + 2);
        x++;
        if (x == getWidth() - 25) {
            right = false;
            up = false;
        }
    } else if (!right && !up) {
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 20);               // body - drawn in terms of x
        g.drawLine(x - 5, y + 15, x + 5, y + 15);    // wing
        g.drawLine(x - 2, y, x + 2, y);
        y++;
        if (y == getHeight() - 25) {
            up = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (x <= getWidth() - 15 && x > 20) {
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + 20, y);               // body - drawn in terms of x
            g.drawLine(x + 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5);    // wing
            g.drawLine(x + 20, y - 2, x + 20, y + 2);
            x--;
        }
        if (x == 20) {
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 20);               // body - drawn in terms of x
            g.drawLine(x - 5, y + 5, x + 5, y + 5);    // wing
            g.drawLine(x - 2, y + 20, x + 2, y + 20);
            y--;
        }
        if (y == 10) {
            right = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it! Here's an image showing how it looks like:

[image]

### Additional tips:

1. Don't call `frame.setSize()` but override `MovePlane`'s JPanel `getPreferredSize()` to return a fixed size of `300, 300`.
2. Always place your GUI in the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) by wrapping your `main` method like this:

   ```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //Your code here
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. Related to tip #1, call `frame.pack();` instead of `frame.setSize()` after overriding `JPanel`'s `getPreferredSize()` :)